# i18n and TideSDK app

Tags: tidesdk, tidekit

I can't find any information about this. Is it possible to implement i18n in tidesdk application? Is yes, how do you achieve this? I need to implement i18n in todesdk app, with possibility to easly add new languages.

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple solution for that, and is using jQuery and a localization plugin.

you store your localizations on a json structure per language and you setup the language as you need.

https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize

this should help you.